# DE solution's uniqueness and convexity

Tags: matrices, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I am lost and don't know how to prove the following:

> If $M$ is a positive definite symmetric square matrix and if $\overrightarrow {v}(t)$ is a solution of:
>
> $$\overrightarrow {v'}(t) = M\overrightarrow {v}(t),\qquad t\in[0,T]$$
>
> Then,
>
> 1) $\phi(t) = \ln(\|\overrightarrow {v(t)}\|^2) $ is a convex funciton,
>
> 2) Solution of the differential equation is unique.

Comment: Hi, I'm checking out this question per your request.  I'll see what I can do.  Be patient, it may take a little while.  By the way, nice question, ***endorsed!*** Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Well, I'm giving it a try, anyway . . . might take a couple hours since I'm sort of tied up right now . . . will keep you posted.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I really appreciate that you are wasting your time with my question! you are the best. I will be up all night, so doesn't matter if you answer it now or a few hours later :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the kind words; I'm on the case, but still distracted by other business; hopefully by later today I'll have something for you!

Comment: @RobertLewis thank you so much! I am stuck with this question on my mind so I will not be able to sleep probably :D

Comment: Hey, don't loose any sleep over it!  I'm on it right now, but can't say exactly when I'll post . . . have a few previous commitments this afternoon.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis thank you so much sir! you can post it part by part whenever you have time, but it is ok otherwise also. thank you soo much again!

Comment: I added the "convex analysis" tag; after working awhile on your questions, I found that showing $\phi(t)$ covex to be most challenging.  Hope to post soon.  Sorry about the delay.  Get some sleep.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I'll be waiting for your answer. :)

Comment: It's nearly done;  this one was harder than I expected!  Meanwhile, get some rest!  Cheers!

Comment: Finally posted, but still needs a few edits.  Sorry about the delay.  Hope you can sleep better now!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Omg sir! Thank you soo much!

Comment: You are more than welcome!  Glad to help out..

Comment: Also, thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for any real square matrix of size $n$, symmetric or not, positive definite or not, the equation

$\vec v'(t) = M \vec v(t), \; t \in [0, T], \tag{1}$

with the initial condition $\vec v(0)$ at $t = 0$, *always* admits the unique solution

$\vec v(t) = e^{Mt}\vec v(0); \tag{2}$

that (2) solves (1) is easily seen by direct differentiation; (2) yields:

$\vec v'(t) = (e^{Mt})' \vec v(0) = Me^{Mt} \vec v(0) = Mv(t). \tag{3}$

Existence *and* uniqueness also follow from the standard theory of ordinary differential equations, since the linear vector field $M \vec v$ satisfies a Lipschitz condtion on all of $\Bbb R^n$:

$\Vert M \vec v_1 - M \vec v_2 \Vert = \Vert M (\vec v_1 - \vec v_2) \Vert \le \Vert M \Vert \Vert v_1 - v_2 \Vert. \tag{4}$

Further information on the relationship of Lipschitz continuity to existence and uniqueness may be found [in this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), or in any number of standard texts on ordinary differential equations.  Thus, based upon general theoretical considerations, we may consider item (2) in this question as being resolved; we turn to item (1).

To address the convexity of

$\phi(t) = \ln(\Vert \vec v(t) \Vert^2) \tag{5}$

we re-introduce the hypothesized symmetry and positive definiteness of the matrix $M$.  Since $M$ is symmetric, it is possessed of $n$ real eigenvalues $\lambda_i$  and an  orthonormal eigenbasis $\vec e_i$ of $\Bbb R^n$, $1 \le i \le n$, such that

$M \vec e_i = \lambda_i \vec e_i \tag{6}$

for each $i$; since $M$ is positive definite, each $\lambda_i = \langle \vec e_i, M \vec e_i \rangle > 0$; we may expand $\vec v(0)$ in terms of the $\vec e_i$, obtaining

$\vec v(0) = \sum_1^n c_i \vec e_i, \tag{7}$

where as usual $c_i = \langle \vec v(0), \vec e_i \rangle$, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ being the ordinary euclidean inner product on $\Bbb R^n$.  We may then express the solution (2) to (1) in the form

$\vec v(t) = e^{Mt} \vec v(0) = e^{Mt}(\sum_1^n c_i \vec e_i) = \sum_1^n c_i e^{Mt} \vec e_i; \tag{8}$

we recall that (6) implies

$e^{Mt} \vec e_i = e^{\lambda _i t} e_i;  \tag{9}$

and thus (8) yields

$\vec v(t) = \sum_1^n c_i e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i; \tag{10}$

we compute

$\Vert v(t) \Vert^2 = \langle v(t), v(t) \rangle = \langle \sum_1^n c_i e^{\lambda_i t} \vec e_i, \sum_1^n c_j ^{\lambda_j t} \vec e_j \rangle = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n c_i c_j e^{\lambda_i t} e^{\lambda_j t} \langle \vec e_i, \vec e_j \rangle$
$= \sum_{i,j = 1}^n c_i c_j e^{\lambda_i t} e^{\lambda_j t} \delta_{ij} = \sum_1^n c_i^2 e^{2\lambda_i t}.  \tag{12}$

We thus have

$\phi(t) = \ln (\Vert v(t) \Vert^2) = \ln(\sum_1^n c_i^2 e^{2\lambda_i t});  \tag{13}$

scrutinizing (13), we see that we may, by re-indexing the $c_i$, $\lambda_i$ if necessary, assume that $c_i \ne 0$ for $1 \le i \le m \le n$; then this equation reads

$\phi(t) = \ln (\sum_1^m c_i^2 e^{2\lambda_i t}) \tag{14}$

with each $c_i^2 > 0$.  This being the case, we may write

$\phi(t) = \ln (\sum_1^m e^{\ln c_i^2} e^{2\lambda_i t}) = \ln (\sum_1^m e^{2\lambda_i t + \ln c_i^2}); \tag{15}$

$\phi(t)$ is convex on $[0, T]$ provided that

$\phi(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2) \le s\phi(t_1) + (1 - s) \phi(t_2) \tag{16}$

for any $t_1, t_2 \in [0, T]$; here $s \in [0, 1]$. To the end of estsblishing (16), we introduce the fact that the *log-sum-exp* functions are themselves convex; that is, letting

$\vec x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k), \tag{17}$

the log-sum-exp function $f(\vec x)$ of $\vec x$ is defined by the formula

$f(\vec x) = f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k) = \ln (\sum_1^k e^{x_i}); \tag{18}$

if we also set

$\vec y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k), \tag{19}$

we have

$f(s \vec x + (1 - s) \vec y) \le sf(\vec x) + (1 - s) f(\vec y) \tag{20}$

for all $s$ as above.  If we now take $k = m$ and set

$\vec x(t) = (2\lambda_1 t + \ln c_1^2, 2\lambda_2 t + \ln c_2^2, \ldots, 2\lambda_m t + \ln c_m^2), \tag{21}$

then we may write

$\phi(t) = f(\vec x(t)); \tag{22}$

from the convexity of $f(x)$ we have, for any $t_1, t_2 \in [0, T]$,

$f(s\vec x(t_1) + (1 - s) \vec x(t_2))$
$\le sf(x(t_1)) + (1 - s)f(\vec x(t_2)) = s\phi(t_1) + (1 - s)\phi(t_2).  \tag{23}$

We conclude our argument with the observation that

$s\vec x(t_1) + (1 - s)\vec x(t_2) = \vec x(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2), \tag{24}$

which may be seen by examining the components of (24):

$s(2\lambda_i t_1 + \ln c_i^2) + (1 - s)(2\lambda_i t_2 + \ln c_i^2) = 2\lambda_i (st_1 + (1 - s) t_2) + \ln c_i^2; \tag{25}$

(23) thus becomes

$f(\vec x(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2) \le s\phi(t_1) + (1 - s)\phi(t_2); \tag{26}$

since

$\phi(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2) = f(\vec x(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2)), \tag{27}$

we find that

$\phi(st_1 + (1 - s)t_2) \le s\phi(t_1) + (1 - s)\phi(t_2)); \tag{28}$

that is, $\phi(t) = \ln (\Vert \vec v \Vert^2)$ is convex on $[0, T]$.